# Capture difference in streaming data every 5 mins

Tags: excel, vba

I have a streaming sheet which recieves all the data. Made another sheet called Workarea where that data is copied using =Streaming! B1and so on. Now I need one entire column value difference every 5 minutes. The value keeps increasing and starts with 0 every morning. Will want to add another sheet 5mins and get the difference there. Total cells are 98  B1:B98.
I did try the xlspecialpaste command but it subtracts destination from copied cells and gives the value as negative. Also copies the formula so data keeps changing as per original streaming data. 
Thanks

This is what I have.

```
Option Explicit 
Public dTime As Date 

Sub ValueStore() 
Dim nr As Long 
With Worksheets("Sheet1") 
.Range("B1:B98").Copy 
.Range("C1:C98").PasteSpecial _ Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationSubtract 
End With 

Call StartTimer 

End Sub 

Sub StartTimer() 
dTime = Now + TimeValue("00:05:00") 
Application.OnTime dTime, "ValueStore", Schedule:=True 
End Sub 

Sub StopTimer() 
On Error Resume Next 
Application.OnTime dTime, "ValueStore", Schedule:=False 
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show the code you've started with please.

Comment: This is what I have. Problem is its coping the formula and doing destination - copied cells Option Explicit
Public dTime As Date

Sub ValueStore()
Dim nr As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
 .Range("B1:B98").Copy
 .Range("C1:C98").PasteSpecial _
  Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationSubtract
End With

        Call StartTimer
End Sub


Sub StartTimer()
    dTime = Now + TimeValue("00:05:00")
    Application.OnTime dTime, "ValueStore", Schedule:=True
End Sub

Sub StopTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime dTime, "ValueStore", Schedule:=False
End Sub

Comment: So what is the issue here?

Comment: It's copying the formula which is =sheet! O9 instead of value and that keeps updating. Also subtraction is happening destination cells - copied cells giving a negative value which keeps adding up. I need the difference in value every 5 minutes. Here after 5 minutes destination is same as copied cells.

Comment: Recorded in 5min intervals, or just overwritten with the delta?

Comment: It is adding the values if i keep it as Range ("C1:C98").Value = .Range("B1:B98).Value

Comment: I do not recommend copy and paste in vba, but in this case to copy the value and subtract you can use: `Range("C1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlSubtract, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False`

Comment: Getting a compile error with this, sorry i am a novice   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VTnVWe5rZoEVDY7zAIrdb6VpuiGZ8HUe

Comment: Ok i got this to work but same problem. destination cells - copied cells. i need it the other way around . Copied cells - destination cells

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you have a formula in Column B which updates all the time and you want a "snapshot" of the values every 5 minutes.

To do that you can simply use `range(destinationRange).Value = range(sourceRange).Value`

To do a calculation a simple loop will do the trick:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim i as Long
     For i = 1 to 98
         If IsNumeric(.Cells(i,3).Value) then
            .Cells(i,3).Value = .Cells(i,2).Value - .Cells(i,3).Value
         Else
            .Cells(i,3).Value = .Cells(i,2).Value
         End If
     Next
End With
```

Instead of copying the range.

Comment: I actually need the difference in values every 5 minutes. So if it cos the values and subtracts copied cells value -  destination cells value then I have a solution

Comment: @Kevin So `.Range("C1:C98").Value = .Range("B1:B98").Value - .Range("C1:C98").Value` ?

Comment: Tried this and get an error when i start timer "Runtime error "13" type mismatch                                                                                                        Sub ValueStore()
Dim nr As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
     .Range("C2:C98").Value = .Range("B2:B98").Value - .Range("C2:C98").Value
End With

Comment: Do you understand what the code does, that I posted? Because I don't actually understand which number you want to subtract from which number, @Kevin The error stems from there not being a number in Column C

Comment: ok let make all 0 and try it . in the morning when we start its empty.

Comment: ok let make all 0 and try it . in the morning when we start its empty.

Comment: Still the same error . Using this                                                                                      
.Range("C2:C98").Value = .Range("B2:B98").Value - .Range("C2:C98").Value

have put in 1 in c1:c98
Sorry i am not a programmer but i do understand what your code is doing .

Comment: @Kevin I edited my answer, check if this works for your case. I still don't understand which numbers you want to subtract though

Comment: @Nacorid Your edit should work, but it would be worth adding a check on each loop to see if the destination cell contains a number value before proceeding, if there is no number then you can add a warning message box / skip that loop. This will prevent any errors.

Comment: See thes pics of the vb script and sheet
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1R3RMSzMgZ_gcATAjxQqeAshbQyeqtUQb and https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SqbdeJSkQzXHYGIAU8ChvvGVNoZHLH6U

Comment: You are of course absolutely right @5202456 , added it to my answer

Comment: @Kevin it is still unclear which numbers you want to subtract

Comment: @Nacroid Column B has streaming numerical data which keeps on increasing. Starts from 0 in the morning .I want to capture the diffirence for every 5 minutes in column C . What i am basically trying to do is capture the number of trades done in a stock every 5 minutes. So basically 5 minutes into the morning it would be in 1000 and end the day in millions or billions.

Comment: @Kevin So you only want the last 5 minutes of trades in column C? My revised code should do what you want

Comment: Here is the file .  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1E-U69ppsiFAnH1TvNOaa0HXA348qPXqx

Comment: The code is tested and works for me. Are you sure you implemented it correctly, @Kevin ?

Comment: @Nacroid Thanks a ton i got it to work . Mistake i did was i = 1 to 98 changed that to 2 to 98 as first row had text headers.